# How can I match all data between two date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend, aggregation

I want to get data between two dates if I give date 01-01-2022 and date 09-10-2022 I want to display all data between these two dates I did this example bellow:

```
 let logs = await this.profileModel.aggregate([
    {
      // finish here date
      // finish settlement
      // finish logReport
      $match: {
        bindedSuperAdmin: name,
        // transactionDate: { $gte: startDate, $lt: endDate },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'tpes',
        localField: 'nameUser',
        foreignField: 'merchantName',
        as: 'tpesBySite',
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'logs',
        localField: 'tpesBySite.terminalId',
        foreignField: 'terminalId',
        // as: 'logsByTpes',
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              
              transactionDate: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate },
              // transactionDate: { $in: [startDate, endDate] },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: 'logsByTpes',
      },
    },

    { $unwind: '$tpesBySite' },

    { $unwind: '$logsByTpes' },
    {
      $project: {
        // bindedSuperAdmin: '$bindedSuperAdmin',
        // bindedBanque: '$bindedBanque',
        // bindedClient: '$bindedClient',

        snTpe: '$tpesBySite.sn',
        terminalId: '$tpesBySite.terminalId',

        transactionDate: '$logsByTpes.transactionDate',
        transactionTime: '$logsByTpes.transactionTime',

        outcome: '$logsByTpes.outcome',
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { bank: '$outcome' },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ]);

  return logs;
```

It matches only the given dates but I need to gt all data between these two dates I really get stuck how can I Fix It Please

Comment: You seem to have it commented out right there, try `$gte: new Date(startDate)` instead of just `$gte: startDate`, mongoose does not cast aggregation pipelines.

Comment: Please provide some sample input data. I guess you need to cast **string** `01-01-2022` to a proper `Date` object.

Comment: The probllm was I need to provide all date format like this 2022-09-22T00:00:00.000Z 
my mistake was I match '01-01-2022' with '2022-09-22T00:00:00.000Z'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I need to provide all date format like this `2022-09-22T00:00:00.000Z` my mistake was I match `01-01-2022` with `2022-09-22T00:00:00.000Z`.